# how to hide smth with PHP if there is a specific variable or word in the list

Tags: php, mysql

```
                    <? if (isset($menu_filter_sizes)) { ?>
                     <? for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu_filter_sizes); $i++) { ?>
                            <? if (!empty($menu_filter_sizes[$i]['name'])) { ?>                                    
                            <li>
                                <? if ($page->sp_size == $menu_filter_sizes[$i]['id']) { ?>
                                <? } else { ?><a href=""><? }; ?>
                                    <? echo $menu_filter_sizes[$i]['name']; ?>
                                <? if ($page->sp_size == $menu_filter_sizes[$i]['id']) { ?>
                                <? } else { ?></a><? }; ?>
                                (<? echo $menu_filter_sizes[$i]['quantity']; ?>)
                            </li>
                            <? }; ?>
                        <? }; ?>
                <? }; ?>
```

This code generates a list with different values (e.g. Sizes). And i have in my DB a value which is called **"Nosize"**. This is value for products with no size. Present PHP code that i have it outputs all the values in the list.

HOW with php to hide that value by the name **"Nosize"**??? and show the others values only. in another words, show all values, except "Nosize".

MYSQL:

```
function GetShopFilterSizes($shopid,$category,$fcolor,$fbrand,$fytpe,$fpricefrom,$fpriceto){
    $thisdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
    $sqlquery = "SELECT DISTINCT($this->basesq.size) AS id, $this->basesize.alias, $this->basesizelang.name, COUNT(DISTINCT($this->base.id)) as quantity FROM $this->base LEFT JOIN $this->basesq ON $this->basesq.productid = $this->base.id LEFT JOIN $this->basesize ON $this->basesq.size = $this->basesize.id LEFT JOIN $this->basesizelang ON $this->basesize.id = $this->basesizelang.sizeid AND $this->basesizelang.lang =  '".sql($this->thislang)."' WHERE $this->base.shopid = '".Sql($shopid)."' AND $this->base.exist = 1 AND $this->base.active = 1 AND $this->base.isdeleted = 0";
    if (count($category) > 0) {$sqlquery .= " AND (";};
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($category); $i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {$sqlquery .= "$this->base.categoryid = '".sql($category[$i])."'";}
        else {$sqlquery .= " OR $this->base.categoryid = '".sql($category[$i])."'";};
    };
    if (count($category) > 0) {$sqlquery .= ")";};

    if (!empty($fbrand)) {$sqlquery .= " AND $this->base.brand = '".sql($fbrand)."'";};
    if (!empty($ftype)) {$sqlquery .= " AND $this->base.type = '".sql($ftype)."'";};
    if (!empty($fcolor)) {$sqlquery .= " AND $this->basesq.color = '".sql($fcolor)."' AND $this->basesp.quantity > '0'";};
    if (!empty($fpricefrom)) {$sqlquery .= " AND ($this->base.price >= '".sql($fpricefrom)."')";};
    if (!empty($fpriceto)) {
        $sqlquery .= " AND (
            ($this->base.price <= '".sql($fpriceto)."') OR ($this->base.specialprice IS NOT NULL AND $this->base.specialprice < '".sql($fpriceto)."') OR ($this->base.salesprice IS NOT NULL AND $this->base.salesprice < '".sql($fpriceto)."' AND (($this->base.slprice_datestart IS NULL OR $this->base.slprice_datestart < '".$thisdate."') AND ($this->base.slprice_dateend IS NULL OR $this->base.slprice_dateend > '".$thisdate."')))
        )";
    };
    $sqlquery .= " GROUP BY $this->basesq.size";
    $result = mysql_query($sqlquery) or die(mysql_error()." in file: ".__FILE__.", line: ".__LINE__);
    return GetMySQLResultArray($result);
}
```

the whole HTML text

```
<div class="box manufacturers">
                    <div class="box-heading" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #d8dae5;"><span><? echo $langdata['prlist_size']; ?></span></div>
                    <? if (isset($menu_filter_sizes)) { ?>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <ul>
                            <? for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu_filter_sizes); $i++) { ?>
                                <? if($menu_filter_sizes[$i]['name']!='nosize') { ?>  
                                    <li>
                                    <? if ($page->sp_size == $menu_filter_sizes[$i]['id']) { ?><u>
                                    <? } else { ?><a href="<? echo ClearURL(array('success','size'),array('_size='.$menu_filter_sizes[$i]['alias'])); ?>"><? }; ?>
                                        <? echo $menu_filter_sizes[$i]['name']; ?>
                                    <? if ($page->sp_size == $menu_filter_sizes[$i]['id']) { ?></u>
                                    <? } else { ?></a><? }; ?>
                                    </strong> (<? echo $menu_filter_sizes[$i]['quantity']; ?>)
                                    </li>
                                    <?}else{?>
                                <? }; ?>
                            <? }; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <? }; ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why not just not select it from the database in the first place by using "field != 'Nosize'" in your query?

Comment: Ok i don't mind which way to make it done. But can you tell me more? My php programmer is sick, and I am trying to fix it out, although I know some php...

Comment: I'd highly recommend waiting for your developer to get back, but look into "mysql not equal" or "not like" (assuming you're using mysql). Without seeing the query or the database structure I can't really provide you with a working example

Comment: Ok, in few minutes ill publish the Mysql query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<? if (isset($menu_filter_sizes)) { 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu_filter_sizes); $i++) { 
    if($menu_filter_sizes[$i]['size']!='Nosize') {//check if size is not equal to Nosize
                                
       } 
     } 
   } ?>
```

Also you are opening and closing php tags at every line which is not needed.

*Update: From the OP comments*

you need to take your code outside div

```
      <? if (isset($menu_filter_sizes)) { 
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($menu_filter_sizes); $i++) { 
                if($menu_filter_sizes[$i]['size']!='Nosize') {//check if size is not equal to Nosize
    
    ?>
       <div class="box manufacturers">
    
    
        </div>
    
    <?                                        
      } 
    } 
   } 
 ?>
```

Comment: @user1948524 replace 'size' with your table field name

Comment: if in the list is only 1 value wich is "No size" how can i hidethe whole code? I will place right now the whole HTML code in my main question, unde the MYSQL query. Thanks again!

Comment: @user1948524 do you mean you want to hide div with class="box manufacturers" too??

Comment: mmm well, this way I was thinking also, but it dublicates everything Even the heading box. which is not good if get more then one value in the list.